# Is there a way to programmatically insert a new user into a MyWSAT implementation (Windows Forms user registration)?

Tags: c#, paypal, forms-authentication, authentication, wsat

I'm building a website whose services will be subscription based.  So, not that it matters, but I'm hooked into Paypal for setting up recurring payments.  When the user submits a payment, I get an IPN (Instant Payment Notification) sent to a listener URL on my website.  The code inside this will take the data that Paypal sends it and use it to insert a new user into a MyWSAT implementation.  Currently, I have to manually go to the MyWSAT admin site to insert new users.  Is there a way to simply automate new user registration into MyWSAT?

Or maybe, more appropriately, does anyone know of a Windows Forms authentication implementation that makes it easy to insert new users automatically via code (and generate a temporary password for them)?

My goal is to be able to provide a member's only portion of the site immediately after the user submits a payment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about [MyWSAT](http://mywsat.codeplex.com/) since I do not use it, however, here's what I do know...

Since this is a SQL Server database, I would suggest using SQL Profiler when adding a user. See what comes out of the trace and go from there. With luck, maybe you can use one stored proc to create the user.

Comment: I was thinking the SAME thing just now, seriously :)

Comment: Have you considered looking at the source code to see what's going on behind the scenes?